# How to add a Hypertext link with scrolling to a specific point on that new page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I added a button on my HTML-Page, when clicking on it i get to a new URL (It's like a Hypertext Link "behind" the button) and wanted to know how could I make it so, that the new opened page, will be scrolled down to a specific point on that page and not on the top?

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/Fragment.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine this would work.

```
<a href="www.yoursite.com/newpage.html#id">Link</a>
```

Where ID is the ID of the element you want to scroll to.

Comment: No problem hope it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Add `#id_of_the_element` you wish to link to to the end of the URI.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an anchor to it and it should work.
On your javascript change the location to

```
http://yourwebsite.com/yourpage#somesectionname
```

and in the page define the anchor as

```
<a id="somesectionname">Some Section</a>
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML anchor tag
On your button put something like

```
<a href="http://example.com/filename.html#anchor">Link Text</a>
```

On the other page place `<a name="anchor"></a>` around the element of the page that you want to jump to

Answer (score 1):

Just add the id of the element you wish to scroll to to the end of the URL.

For example [Will's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965815/how-to-add-a-hypertext-link-with-scrolling-to-a-specific-point-on-that-new-page#answer-16965883) has an id of '#answer-16965883` so the URL is:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965815/how-to-add-a-hypertext-link-with-scrolling-to-a-specific-point-on-that-new-page#answer-16965883`

Comment: Like what you did there ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you use a link like

```
<a href="yourPage.html#WhereToScroll">Scrolling link</a>
```

Then on yourPage.html add

```
<a id="WhereToScroll"></a>
```

Where you want the page to scroll to on that page.

More information is available on the [spec](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)