# Hypertext link: from a page forum to another site

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

For years i have wondered is this is possible. I'm trying to send a link to someone with the exact html to send them straight to a point in a page on this forum. i have ready this other question and its not quite this easy.
[How to add a Hypertext link with scrolling to a specific point on that new page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965815/how-to-add-a-hypertext-link-with-scrolling-to-a-specific-point-on-that-new-page)

the page I'm wanting to send someone to is this:
(http://www.torn.com/forums.php#!p=threads&f=13&t=15908489&b=0&a=0&start=660)
now how would i be able to send someone straight to the 7th post in this forum. the post starts with this line of code and that seems to be the only thing i would be able to use to call back to the link I'm trying to send.
`<li class="" data-id="16607863">`


What do i need to change in this anchor tag to make you automatically open page 34 in the forum and scroll straight to the 7th post.

`<a href="http://www.torn.com/forums.php#!p=threads&f=13&t=15908489&b=0&a=0&start=660">Your wish has come true.</a>`


**i can't edit their source code, so i can't make an ID like what you would if you were making the site yourself.**


I really hope i explained it right or asked it in a way it really makes since.

Comment: If you are the owner of the site, you would have to build in the functionality to add anchors to each post. If you are not the owner of the site, it's not possible.

Comment: However, you could change the start value parameter in the URL to `666` which appears to move the post, you are wanting to link to, to the top: http://www.torn.com/forums.php#!p=threads&f=13&t=15908489&b=0&a=0&start=666

Comment: @APAD1 sorry dude but that didn't seem to work for me maybe its safari but ill check other browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Its possible with ID, you must to set `id="something"` and then you will be able to automatticly scroll there with a link, all you have to do is to add `#something` on end of link.

something like this:

```
<h1 id="something">Title</h1>
<p>description.</p>
```

Comment: i know its possible but if you read the question you can see that the site is already made. next time make sure you read and understand what is being asked.

Comment: That is impossible i think, only way to do that is to get ID of the post and add it on end of the link or you can ask website owner to add one ID there.

Comment: Its maybe possible but not with classic html